# How to find the highest and smallest value

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to find highest and smallest value in one function. I have tried it, however I only get the smallest value. This is because the code wasn't read from the first row and the first row contains highest value. This is my code:

```cpp
void price(ifstream& infile) {
    infile.clear();
    infile.seekg(0);

    int year, mall, cafe, expenses;
    infile >> year >> mall >> cafe >> expenses;

    int high_mall{}, high_year{}, high_expenses{};
    int low_mall{}, low_year{}, low_expenses{};

    low_mall = mall;
    low_year = year;
    low_expenses = expenses;

    for (int year{}, mall{}, cafe{}, expenses{};
         nameFile >> year >> mall >> cafe >> expenses;) {
        if (expenses > high_expenses) {
            high_expenses = expenses;
            high_year = year;
            high_mall = mall;
        }
        if (expenses < low_expenses) {
            low_expenses = expenses;
            low_year = year;
            low_mall = mall;
        }
    }

    cout << "Highest expenses are " << high_expenses << "at" << high_year << endl;
    cout << "Total mall that year are " << high_mall << endl;
    cout << "Lowest expenses are " << low_expenses << "at" << low_year << endl;
    cout << "Total mall that year are " << low_mall << endl;
}
```

This is my code. I have tried to remove the first inline and got the highest value but smallest value becomes 0. Does anyone know how to fix it? I am thinking about `std::numeric_limits`. But can I solve this without using it?

Comment: my [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) has some questions: what is your initial value for `low_expenses` ? What value for `expenses` do you need to encounter to get `expenses < low_expenses`?

Comment: You seem to be reading the initial year, mall, cafe, and expenses before entering the loop to read the rest. Any particular reason you're not just initializing *both* the high/low counterparts to those initial-read values before entering the loop. I mean, at the time, they're they only values you've (supposedly) read. Thus they *are* the current high/low watermarks before reading the rest in the loop, aren't they. On a related item, an `else` should appear before the if-low-check in the loop. If it qualified for higher-than-highest, it can't possibly also be lower-than-lowest.

Comment: int low_mall {} , low_year {}, low_expenses {}; - I try to remove this one but then the first row of the file wasn't being read

Comment: Start from fixing compilation errors: https://godbolt.org/z/f735MM3zW and please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: If you're in-code assumption of the first row being successfully read doesn't hold water (you're not checking that because...??), than *none* of this is going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the initial value for `low_expenses` is zero, you will never find any year with lower expenses, unless the expenses are negative. You should initialize your `low_expenses` to the greatest possible integer like this:

```cpp
low_expenses{ std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };
```

If the expenses can be negative, initializing `high_expenses` to the lowest possible value would also help:

```cpp
high_expenses{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
```

You need to include the `<limits>` header for this to work.

Also, as WhozCraig has pointed out, the line

```cpp
infile >> year >> mall >> cafe >> expenses;
```

will discard one row of input. It is not necessary. You could initialize your `low_...` and `high_...` to the values of the first row, but then you might also have to check if the first I/O operation succeeded or not. (in case there are no rows)

Comment: i know about this method and it works however this method wasn't teach by my lecturer. she might think that i was cheating if i use a method that wasn't in her slides

Comment: It is very unlikely that you will be under suspicion for `std::numeric_limits`. It is very commonly known, and used in many code samples for finding minimum/maximum values. Students can be expected to inform themselves beyond lecture slides.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your highest and lowest content after intial read prior to entering the loop to read the rest.

Example:

```
void price(ifstream &infile)
{
    infile.clear();
    infile.seekg(0);

    int year, mall, cafe, expenses;
    if (infile >> year >> mall >> cafe >> expenses)
    {
        int high_mall{mall}, high_year{year}, high_expenses{expenses};
        int low_mall{mall}, low_year{year}, low_expenses{expenses};

        while (infile >> year >> mall >> cafe >> expenses)
        {
            if (expenses > high_expenses)
            {
                high_expenses = expenses;
                high_year = year;
                high_mall = mall;
            }
            else if (expenses < low_expenses)
            {
                low_expenses = expenses;
                low_year = year;
                low_mall = mall;
            }
        }

        cout << "Highest expenses are " << high_expenses << "at" << high_year << endl;
        cout << "Total mall that year are " << high_mall << endl;

        cout << "Lowest expenses are " << low_expenses << "at" << low_year << endl;
        cout << "Total mall that year are " << low_mall << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is use thins which are already provided by standard library.
There is [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) which does exactly what you need.

Also it is possible to turn stream into an iterator of some specific data: [std::istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator).

Those two things can be combined into following code:

```cpp
struct Data
{
    int year, mall, cafe, expenses;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Data& data)
{
    return in >> data.year >> data.mall >> data.cafe >> data.expenses;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Data& data)
{
    return out << data.year << ", " << data.mall << ", " << data.cafe << ", " << data.expenses;
}


int main()
{
    auto result = std::minmax_element(std::istream_iterator<Data>{std::cin}, {}, 
        [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.expenses < b.expenses; });

    std::cout << *result.first << '\n';
    std::cout << *result.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EMvjx5Yrq

Answer (score 0):

i try this and it work

```
void price (ifstream & infile)
{

   infile.clear();
   infile.seekg(0);

  int year, mall, cafe, expenses;

  int high_mall {} , high_year {}, high_expenses {};


  int low_mall;
  int low_year;
  int low_expenses;

  for (int year {}, mall {}, cafe {}, expenses {};
   nameFile >> year >> mall >> cafe >> expenses; )
{

    if (expenses > high_expenses)
    {
        high_expenses = expenses;
        high_year = year;
        high_mall = mall;
    }
     if (expenses < low_expenses)
    {
        low_expenses = expenses;
        low_year = year;
        low_mall = mall;
    }
}

    cout << "Highest expenses are " << high_expenses << "at" << high_year << endl;
    cout << "Total mall that year are " << high_mall << endl ;
    
    cout << "Lowest expenses are " << low_expenses << "at" << low_year << endl;
    cout << "Total mall that year are " << low_mall << endl ;

}
```